# How drop packet with libiptc in c++?

Tags: c++, packet, iptc

Is there a way to drop packets with libiptc c++?,i want a sample code for drop packet with libiptc in c++.

Comment: I am downloading libiptc and see that functions but I do not find a function for droping packets in libiptc.h.

Comment: Do you want to drop specific packets or full blocking of  device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you should write a driver.
for example you can use main_hook function.